# expected token ¿Como puedo arreglar ese problema?

Tags: c++

Cuando agrego esto a mi codigo:

```
while (std::getline(file, str, '\n'))
{
   istringstream iss(str);
   vector<string> line;
   copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(line));
   counter = 0;
```

En la parte de

```
copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), istream_iterator<string>(),
back_inserter(line));
```

Me aparece el error :

> error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

¿Como puedo solucionar ese problema?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/28146/ espero que te sirva.

Comment: No veo que exista problema con el código que has incluido. Quizás si indicas el código completo, con archivos de cabecera y declaraciones previas, y qué compilador estás utilizando (por las banderas a tener activas).